# Mail server: shall I set up a sub-domain name?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I am trying to put in place a mail server following this tutorial: http://www.starbridge.org/spip/spip.php?article12 
Before starting I was wondering if I had ta create a virtual domain on apache.

my hostname is: server01
my domaine name is (for the example): domain.net

do I have to create a sub domain name mail.doamin.net or server01.domain.net

I am a bit confused when I see in different tutorials the use of url like hostname.domain.net (is that the FQDN?)
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only need a virtual domain in Apache if you're going to run some type of webmail application (SquirrelMail, Roundcube, etc.)

The hostname  of `host.example.net` is important for a couple of reasons. First, it allows you to assign specific services such as mail and web requests for your domain to be routed to particular servers if you need those services running on dedicated servers. Second, it allows that manipulation to be done in your DNS records rather than having to try routing specific ports to specific machines once the traffic reaches your network.

Just make sure that you put an MX record entry in your DNS records so that mail service is properly routed. The MX record can point to your actual `hostname` or it can refer to a CNAME record that points to your `hostname`.

A FQDN is any domain name that resolves to an actual `hostname` IP address.

**EDIT**
To clarify an example of DNS records you would need, it would look something like:

```
example.net           IN  A      12.34.56.78
server01.example.net  IN  A      12.34.56.78
mail.example.net      IN  MX     server01.example.net
www.example.net       IN  CNAME  example.net
```

I'm ignoring the TTL and the MX priority values as you will set those when modifying your DNS and can use the default TTL value; an MX priority of `10` is pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks again for your clear answer. So if I get you well 1. I need a virtual domain name called for example 'mail.exemple.net' with my hostname being the name of my server: 'server01'. To work properly I need to put an MX record for 'mail.exemple.net' to point to server01. In my DNS I will have exemple.net and mail.exemple.net pointing to the same server: server01 (I only have one server. Am I correct?

Comment: @Raphael_b See the edit made to my answer.